# Pytest-asyncio not moving to next statement when using with pyppeteer

Tags: python, pytest, puppeteer, pyppeteer, pytest-asyncio

I am trying to run Pyppeteer with pytest but after launching chromium it's not going to the next statement.

```
import asyncio
import pytest
from pyppeteer import launch

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_BackendWeb():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await pyppeteer.new_page()
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/')
```

After running this browser is launched but the new page is not opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `browser.new_page` instead `pyppeteer.new_page`:

```
page = await browser.new_page()
```